# Sequelize (with Postgres) - Define a new model with engine = postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

Scenario: I am dealing with a database which is running both postgres and infobright, where infobright is set to `default engine`.

Goal: Have Sequelize create a table in postgres

Problem: Sequelize is creating table in Infobright by default.

Detailed Explanation:

So when I am trying to define a model which look like:

```
sequelize.define('mymodel', {
        file_name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
    }, {
        schema: 'myschema'
    });
```

The sql that get generated looks like:

```
create
    table
        if not exists "myschema"."mymodel"(
            "id" serial,
            "file_name" varchar(255),
            "createdAt" timestamp with time zone not null,
            "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone not null,
            primary key("id")
        );
```

NOTE: Because `with (engine = postgres)` is missing, the system tries to create table in the default engine i.e. infobright, which is not what I expect it to do.

Expected SQL

```
create
    table
       if not exists "myschema"."mymodel"(
            "id" serial,
            "file_name" varchar(255),
            "createdAt" timestamp with time zone not null,
            "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone not null,
            primary key("id")
        ) with (
             engine = postgres
        );
```

Note: Executing the above generates a table in postgres.

I tried specifying engine in sequelize as well as model configuration, but it doesn't work.

Questions: How shall I configure Sequelize or my model so that it generates the expected sql. Open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: There is no need to add `with oids = false` in any modern Postgres version as that has been the default for ages. So there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how do I create the table in postgres then, its creating in infobright